# Is it ungrammatical to say "good morning" when it is not morning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, usage, phrases

Is there a grammatical rule that applies to saying "good morning" when it is not morning?

Comment: What are you saying? Your English is hard to follow, please elaborate. Are you asking if it's grammatically wrong to say "good morning" when it is not morning? If so, there's nothing grammatically wrong with that, just that it is a false statement (it's not morning, so how could it be good?).

Comment: "Good morning" is not to be confused with "Good day", "Have a nice day" or "Nice meeting you"

Answer (score 5):

Greetings are not controlled by grammar, but how we perceive the passage of the day. In most english speaking countries, this is done by time (hours and minutes), unlike in muslim countries where the stages of the day relate to prayer times, which in turn are related to the state of the sun.

This causes confusion for arabic speakers, who use one greeting (equivalent to good morning) at any time before sunset, and different one for any time after sunset.

The British approach is to say "Good Morning" at any time before 12:00. After midday, we say "Good Afternoon" until about 18:00, and from then on we say "Good Evening". The boundary between afternoon and evening is quite flexible, but between morning and afternoon it is not.

Comment: What you say equivalent for Arabic speaker and is there any difference in American and Britisher greeting for good morning

Comment: @abmasood There is no difference between American and British "good ___" greetings. I'm American, and JavaLatte's approach (which I'm assuming is the British one, from the answer) is the same as what I would do.

Comment: I agree with everything said here. That said, I'll point out that saying "good morning" at, say, 12:20 (or "good afternoon" at 11:30) is not really considered a social faux pas or anything like that. Normally, people simply chalk it up to losing track of the time, perhaps smile about it, and shrug it off.

Answer (score 1):

Saying "good morning"  when it is not morning time is a common mistake made by English speakers, but it is not technically a violation of grammar rules. Rather, sometimes a person is unaware of the time of day, or merely misspeaks.

Comment: It's means that saying morning any time is grammatically wrong

Comment: Yes, if it is not morning, you would be saying something that is not correct, even though you are not violating rules of grammar.

Comment: Oo thnx but some guys say that it's rule of any chaw sir to saying gud morning is right